# How to get a result for $\int{\sqrt{a^2 \left(\sin{a x}-2 \sin{2 a x}\right)^2+1} \, \mathrm{d}x}$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, trigonometry

I want to obtain the result of this integral where $\mathbb{R}\ni a,x>0$

$$\int{\sqrt{a^2 \left(\sin{a x}-2 \sin{2 a x}\right)^2+1} \, \mathrm{d}x}$$

but Mathematica does not give an answer. Of course, `NIntegrate` works for a given parameter $a$, but I am interested in a general result in terms of $a$.

```
Integrate[Sqrt[1 + a^2 (Sin[a x] - 2 Sin[2 a x])^2], x]
```

Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: Any restriction on x and a? real? complex? range of values?

Comment: it does not look like there is analytical solution to this. tried Rubi and FriCAS and both can't do it.

Comment: Is the indefinite integral required? If not, could you add the supposed range of integration to your post? Your `NIntegrate` results would be helpful too.

Comment: @Gravifer Since I need to obtain the results on the domain in terms of $\pi$, I prefered to obtain the analytical result instead of numerical ones. The range of $x$ for example $ 
  \frac{2\pi}{a} <x<  \frac{3\pi}{a}   $

Comment: `but it gives result for a specific value of a`. I am using Using 12.2. it does not evaluate even for specific `a` value. Screen shot   ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i1Fu.png)  Can you post screen shot showing it evaluating for specific `a` value?

Comment: @Nasser Use NIntegrate instead of Integrate

Comment: [@sara69](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/76607/sara96) Sometimes explicit formula exists for specific definite integrals but non for indefinite ones.

Comment: `Use  NIntegrate instead of Integrate` oh yes, ofcourse `NIntegrate` should work. After all, it is numerical. I thought we are all talking about `Integrate` here.

Comment: @Nasser  Of course, we are all talking about Integrate here, but it seems that does not work :)